# What is your data model for recurrent event?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, data-modeling

For instance something like Google Calendar, where we can:

- Add simple event
- Add recurring event

  - every week
  - every monday/tuesday
  - etc.
- Delete an instance of a recurring event
- Change all following recurrent event
- etc.

I have an `events` with the primary event "Event#1" for instance and its instances "Event#2" and "Event#3" that have an event_id foreign key to the primary event, e.g. 1

What do you think? Should I use the iCal spec somehow?

Comment: What database are you using? Some have better time support than others. The iCal spec is probably most useful for the sorts of calendaring issues which will come up.

Comment: I use PostgreSQL

Comment: You're in luck, it has great date/time facilities. [Timestamp ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) are particularly useful. However, calendaring is hard. More information about what you intend to do would help with answering.

Answer (score 2):

Two key things:

- Split the event from its schedule.
- Split the recurring schedule definition from its individual schedule.

By splitting the event from its schedule, instances of a recurring event can share the same event information like its description and location, while others can use an edited version.

```
events:
  id
  name
  description
  location
  ...
```

By splitting the recurring schedule from its individual schedule makes querying for events much simpler.

```
recurring_event_schedules:
  id
  event_id
  schedule: jsonb
  start_at: timestamp with time zone
```

This is the recurring schedule for an event.

Recurring schedules get complicated. You could have multiple tables for each type of recurring period (annual, biannual, daily, monthly, weekly, etc...) or punt and use [jsonb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) to store the spec. The spec might be `{ "period": "weekly", "days": [1,2,3,4,5] }` for every weekday. Reference the iCal spec and good calendaring software for what sorts of repeat events you'd want and other attributes.

jsonb is not a panacea, but this table is only for reference to generate and update events. It is not used for runtime querying. For that there's a second table.

Then generate individual scheduled events from this, out to a configurable limit.

```
event_schedules:
  id
  event_id
  recurrent_event_schedule_id
  schedule: tztsrange
```

This table is simple. What event, when, and what recurring schedule it was generated from.

Since you're using Postgres, rather than separate start/end fields, use a [timestamp range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN). These are supported by [special operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-range.html) to determine if a time is inside a range, or if ranges overlap, and so on.

[Rails will accept Range types](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#range-types), but it does not directly support the operators. For example, `EventSchedule.where("duration @> ?::date", Date.new(2014, 2, 12))` finds all events happening on 2014-02-12.

If you want to edit an individual scheduled event, copy its Event, edit it, and link the EventSchedule to that new Event.

If you want to change the recurring event schedule, select the event_schedules by recurrent_event_schedule_id.

If you want to change the event for all scheduled events, edit the Event linked to the RecurringEventSchedule.

---

In this way you can define complex recurring events and query the simple concrete events.